# Manipulating Javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects and need to create a new array which contains the values of a specific key within the objects. Is there a more elegant way than the following code (note: without using anything more than JQuery). Expected result is: 455, 387, 495

```
var arr=[{sid:387,rank:2},{sid:455,rank:1},{sid:364,rank:4},{sid:495,rank:3}];
var topThreeTemp = arr.filter(function(a){return a.rank<4;}).sort(function(a,b){return a.rank>b.rank;});
var topThreeSIDs=[];
for(var i=0;i<topThreeTemp.length;i++){
    topThreeSIDs.push(topThreeTemp[i].sid);
}
console.log(topThreeSIDs.join(", "));
```

Comment: `topThreeSIDs = topThreeTemp.map(t => t.sid)`

Comment: `Array.map()` so something like `topThreeTemp.map(function( item ) { return item.sid; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ES6 `map`, instead of `for` and ES6 arrow functions (syntax sugars):

```js
const arr = [
 { sid: 387,rank: 2 },
 { sid: 455,rank: 1 },
 { sid: 364,rank: 4 },
 { sid: 495,rank: 3 }
]

const topThreeSIDs = arr
  .filter(({ rank }) => rank < 4)
  .sort((a, b) => a.rank > b.rank)
  .map(({ sid }) => sid)
  

console.log(topThreeSIDs.join(', '))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could filter, sort with delta, slice and map `sid` as result array.

```js
var array = [{ sid: 387, rank: 2 }, { sid: 455, rank: 1 }, { sid: 364, rank: 4 }, { sid: 495, rank: 3 }],
    top3 = array
        .filter(({ rank }) => rank < 4)
        .sort((a, b) => a.rank - b.rank)
        .slice(0, 3)
        .map(({ sid }) => sid);

console.log(top3.join(", "));
```

Comment: Apparently there's no need for the slice, as it seems ranks are unique and they're already taking the ones smaller than 4

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, actually right, but if you have more data, you need to slice for top 3.

Comment: @NinaScholz - As you are filtering on based on rank ( < 4), and rank being unique, there will never be case when there will be more than 3 records left after filter. I think this is what Federico meant.

Comment: @NinaScholz : Yes, this is useful since the implicit assumption that ranks are unique is not necessarily true. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
var arr=[{sid:387,rank:2},{sid:455,rank:1},{sid:364,rank:4},{sid:495,rank:3}];

var result = arr.filter(({rank}) => rank < 4).sort((a,b) => a.rank > b.rank).map(({sid}) => sid);
console.log(result.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function pluck(objs, name, condition) {
        var sol = [];
        for (var i in objs) {
            if (objs[i].hasOwnProperty(name) && condition && condition(objs[i])) {
                // console.log(objs[i][name]);
                sol.push(objs[i][name]);
            }
        }
        return sol;
    }

    var arr = [{sid: 387, rank: 2}, {sid: 455, rank: 1}, {sid: 364, rank: 4}, {sid: 495, rank: 3}];
    var pluckedArray = pluck(arr, sid, function (item) {
        return item.rand < 4; // your custom condition
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

How about iterate the array only once, and build the resultant array?

`arr.reduce((r, {rank, sid})=>(rank < 4 && (r[rank -1] = sid), r), [])`

```js
var arr = [{ sid: 387, rank: 2 }, { sid: 455, rank: 1 }, { sid: 364, rank: 4 }, { sid: 495, rank: 3 }],
    top3 = arr.reduce((r, {rank, sid})=>(rank < 4 && (r[rank -1] = sid), r), []);
    
console.log(top3);
```

Note: When you need top 3 within highest rank `4` and also know ranks are unique, you can use this. If ranks are not unique you can use `r.splice(rank-1, 0, sid)` instead of `r[rank-1] = sid` and `slice` top 3 at the end.